# A better alternative for expression 'visually rich'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

So is it correct to use such expression or there is a better word or phrase to express that? In case someone needs an example sentence (I have doubts regarding this), I'm not going to use the expression in a specific context. It's going to be just a standalone expression or word, referring to real-world objects in general.

EDIT: To be more precise, I'd like to express the rich texture and non-flat structure of the surface of some objects, visualised on screen. Also it can be more poetic, not obviously straightforward

Comment: Without context, this is almost impossible. What do you mean by *rich* - complex? rewarding? opulent?

Comment: @JHCL I think rich in sense having rich texture and non-flat (three-dimensional with some decorative elements) surface. It's going to be applied to some objects, drawn on a screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand probably ***[precious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/precious)*** may convey the meaning you are referring to. Precious is often associated with valuable  stones (diamonds, sapphires etc.) for instance, and it carries the  connotation of value and richness that can be used generically and figuratively as in : a precious book, a precious initiative or a precious texture. In you specific example you can also use ***elaborated/decorated texture*** to contrast the idea of a flat, plain one.

Comment: I guess _elaborate_ is the right word.

Answer (score 2):

How about *ornate?*

> 1 :  marked by elaborate rhetoric or florid style
>
> 2 :  elaborately or excessively decorated

From [Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ornate)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "*complex texture*" may fit or, if you want to emphasis its artistical aspect, you may use the adjective **flamboyant**.

> "flamboyant" definition: strikingly bold or brilliant; showy; conspicuously dashing and
>   colorful; ornate; elaborately styled.

[image: ![enter image description here]